# CodeIgniter Template Library

Tags: php, templates, codeigniter

I am using CodeIgniter with [Template Library](http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/) and have set up my template view file. Part of my template that doesn't change from page to page displays data from a database.

What is the best way to include this data in my template?

Comment: This does not work for you? - http://williamsconcepts.com/ci/codeigniter/libraries/template/reference.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the content doesn't change very often, something like the user's name, I would store it in the session and call it from there. Otherwise, if you really need to query it on every page request, I would create a base controller (MY_Controller) then create and assign a protected var that you can access from your controllers.